# Geometry Nodes Boolean difference between mesh and boundary box

Tags: geometry-nodes, boolean-modifier

I have been racking my brain on this topic but I am trying to create a ceiling generator and I want to remove extra geometry if I have an irregular shaped room. The only thing I have been able to work out is using the mesh geometry itself and somehow utilizing the bounding box node, but then I get stuck on how I can get the difference between these two elements. How can I get the mesh I need to remove the exess geometry?

Below are the picture examples I am working on.
[image]
[image]

Comment: please don't ask "bonus questions" - this site has some "rules". One of them is: Ask only one questions. If you have more questions, just open up a new one. Thx.

Comment: I think you'ere going to have to tell us in more detail what your generator does.. why the ceiling can't be generated _from_ the room, directly. Is it tiling, or something?

Comment: Yes, it is tiling. This is an exercise I wanted to do to see if I can create a realistic model that included all the physical elements. I found the solution down below.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured it out! At least one way of doing it. The reason for this question was so I could remove any areas of the ceiling that I don't want to show. Like for a room that is shaped like an "L".

[image: Room Boundary]

[image: Box to use as boolean]

This shows the raw geometry before the modifier. I just took the edges from the walls I created for the room and used this mesh as my foundation for the ceiling.

This box is what I want to cut from.

[image: Group of model to use for Boolean]

I will try to explain what this does. The top half of the group creates a plane from the original mesh. This means I have a workable face to extrude from. The nodes below uses the bounding box node to create a plane that is the overall size of the mesh. I then used the boolean node to remove the portion of the bounding box mesh which leaves me with only the object that I will use to remove parts of the ceiling.
This Idea came from Blender Bash's Youtube video which explains what I did in the top portion and why iit works.

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=45O51Up5qxw&t=585s

Hope this will help other people. I will even leave a link to this exact file for those who want to go deeper into what I did.  Is the practical, maybe not, but its been a fun project.

[image]